# PDFSharp seems to be failing to open certain PDF documents

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I have a program that adds a second page to PDFs submitted to the website.  I use C# and PDFSharp.  Most documents work fine, but a few users are getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout;

PdfDocument rosterInput = PdfReader.Open(FilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

PdfPage rpage = rosterInput.Pages[0];
```

The error occurs on the second line.  When I debug, it says PageCount = 0, which is weird because it is a 1 page document.

Comment: I don't see *any* error checking or error handling in your code. That's what happens.

Comment: It could be that the input PDF is corrupt i.e. the page dictionary is missing the appropriate `NumKids` entry. You can try dumping the metadata and check, if your library supports that.

Comment: The error gets caught before the user sees it.

Comment: Maybe the files you can't load are in PDF fromat not yet supported. Take a look at this link: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Which_PDF_versions_are_supported_by_PDFsharp_7.

Comment: It is pdf 1.3, which based on your link does seem to have some problems.

Comment: There should be no problems with PDF 1.3 - if the files strictly follow the Adobe PDF Reference. But many third party PDF generators do not follow the PDF Reference. The PDFsharp team is trying to make PDFsharp compatible with files that do not fully adhere to the reference, but they need sample files.

Comment: Also reported on the PDFsharp forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=5758#p5758

Comment: Your third party generator explanation makes sense.  We are mainly seeing this with certain scanners, while all the rest are 100% ok.  I can get an example document with the problem.  Is there are way to upload it?

Comment: PDFSharp has its collective head in the sand when it comes to slightly-out-of-compliance PDFs, viz. that link to their forum posted above. Ghostscript, iTextSharp, any browser released in the last 15 years, etc. can all open the affected documents. Ghostscript and iTextSharp can even repair them without too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much you saved my day!, my only suggestion to improve the solution is to use the memorystream inside on a using block like this:

```
  Using memoryStream As MemoryStream = ReturnCompatiblePdf(File.FullName)
      Dim DocPdf As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(memoryStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
      //Your code here.....
  End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but resolved by the below code, issue was by PDF compatibility.

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(ReturnCompatiblePdf("PDF FILE PATH"), PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)


Private Function ReturnCompatiblePdf(ByVal sFilename As String) As MemoryStream

    Dim reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sFilename)
    Dim output_stream As New MemoryStream

    ' we retrieve the total number of pages
    Dim n As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
    ' step 1: creation of a document-object
    Dim document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
    ' step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
    Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output_stream)
    'write pdf that pdfsharp can understand
    writer.SetPdfVersion(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_4)
    ' step 3: we open the document
    document.Open()
    Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    Dim page As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage

    Dim rotation As Integer

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < n
        i += 1
        document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
        document.NewPage()
        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i)
        If rotation = 90 OrElse rotation = 270 Then
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, _
            reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
        Else
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, _
            0)
        End If
    End While

    '---- Keep the stream open!
    writer.CloseStream = False

    ' step 5: we close the document
    document.Close()

    Return output_stream

End Function
```